# Cache async error from BookSleeve Redis client

Tags: asynchronous, redis, booksleeve

[BookSleeve](http://code.google.com/p/booksleeve/) is very good in performance because it use async IO as much as could.

But the problem is, it may throw fatal exception from asynchronous operation and crash my application.

I know that keyword await can help, but I can't use await for every call.

Is there a way to catch the unhandled exception globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the library are you using? BookSleeve internally observes its own exceptions specifically so that they *should not* cause any crashes, however, you can also:

- handle the `.Error` event
- handle the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event

strictly, neither of these should be required. It is the latter than would prevent app closures, but again: this *should not matter* - unless there is a bug in some of the code and it is missing one or more tasks

But on a more general level, it is good practice to check what happens to your tasks. If you don't want to `await` them, it would probably still be worth subscribing a `ContinueWith` which checks for exceptions. Also, you don't necessarily need to `await`; in many cases, `connection.Wait(result)` is fine too - although this does tie up a primary thread for a *little* longer (but note: it doesn't tie up the multiplexer).